# Should i use Chromium Embedded Framework or .net for my desktop apps?

Tags: c#, html, .net, chromium-embedded

I see a lot of applications made with HTML for UI in Chromium Embedded Framework and I don't understand why they don't use [XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf) like [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) or something similar.

Should I use Chromium Embedded Framework over this? At the same time this uses C++ which is limiting because I only know C#.

Comment: Please revise this question in its entirety.  Use capital letters, ask a clear and direct question, and provide links to, or otherwise explain (in simple terms) the context for the acronyms and abbreviations provided.

Comment: i changed the cef, i want to know why steam spotify etc use cef and not wpf or other thing ;(

Comment: I've edited your question.  It would be a good idea to clarify with the examples you mentioned such as Steam and Spotify etc.  Further, your question is likely open to interpretation and discussion.

Comment: ty, its strange no one answered it ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Writing client apps in HTML/Javascript is good for cross-platform support.

**Details**

WPF is a good framework for developing rich client-side applications *for Windows*. This limitation is important. Developing client-side code in .NET, especially with a framework that's so tied to a single OS, ties you to one specific operating system. The example apps you bring, Steam and Spotify, are both cross-platform apps that have clients for Windows, MacOS and Linux and even browser-based web apps.

It makes sense, when you aim for cross-platform support, to share as much code as you can. There's no point in writing the same login flow, the same network access code, the same logic again and again, once in C# for Windows, in Swift for MacOS and in, say, Python/Qt on Linux. You want to find a common, shared platform that only needs minor modifications on each platform. HTTP/JS using a browser-based app framework (CEF, Electron or whatever) makes sense.

Comment: what about xamarin vs cefsharp ?

Answer (score 0):

I use [CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) because I know a few JavaScript libraries that I really like for graphs ([D3](https://d3js.org/)), charts ([HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/)), and datagrids ([ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)), and I wanted to use them in a desktop application. You say the Chromium Embedded Frameword (CEF) uses C++, and that is true, but you can use CEFSharp to work with it in C#. The cool part is that I can leverage the knowledge I already have with those JavaScript libraries and apply it when creating a desktop application.

I did not use XAML, WPF, etc. because I don't know them well, nor could I find the libraries I wanted to use.

The desktop application I created using CEFSharp and ag-Grid: [EtwViewer](https://github.com/brianstringfellow/EtwViewer)

Comment: Ty but all the cefsahrp can do a wpf form can too ??